# How to upload videos to customers own youtube channel

Tags: java, api, youtube, gdata

I'm creating a small CMS where the users can upload video to youtube using Google.GData.YouTube

For each customer im creating a YouTube application on http://code.google.com/apis/youtube, but I'm really interested in how i can upload to the customers own youtube channel instead of my developer account.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using your developer's account, you should authenticate the customer. The prefered option is using OAuth. See http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication.html